# Halving input but not at each step of a process

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, logarithms, computational-complexity, gcd-and-lcm

I am reading about an algorithm that takes as input $2$ integers and does the following to calculate the GCD:
If both are even then then shift right (=division by $2$) both numbers and repeat
If one is even then shift right (=division by $2$) the even number only and repeat
If both are odd then call the process with $(x - y) , y$ (assuming $x > y)$

Now if both input numbers are a power of $2$ then this process keeps halving the numbers at each step and so the complexity is $log(|x|) + log(|y|)$ (where $|x|$ means the number of bits in $x$)
But in all other cases, we end up interchanging between even/odd at each call i.e.
If we have $2$ even, shift right (i.e. division by 2) will give $2$ odd numbers.
This is since 2 even $\equiv$ $2\cdot(2n + 1), 2\cdot(2k + 1)$
If we have $2$ odds we do the subtraction and we end up with $1$ even and $1$ odd.
This means that each number is halved at every second step.

So what is the complexity in this case? Is it still $log(|x|) + log(|y|)$ even though the halving is done at > 1 step?

Comment: what's the algorithm called?

Comment: @dfish: no idea, I think it is just some optimization trick, and although I understand the logic, I am not sure how to formally figure the complexity (on the length of the bits)

Comment: @dfish: it's called the [binary gcd algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm).

Answer (score 4):

It depends by what you mean by "What is the complexity?"

In order to answer that question, you need a *model* for what sort of operations count as "one step".  If your model is a CPU with a *built-in* $\text{gcd}$ operation (using your algorithm), then your algorithm has time complexity exactly $1$.  (This is probably not the model you should use.)

More practically, you haven't specified what size your integers are.  On an x86 CPU (now somewhat dated), addition of 32-bit integers might take one step…but addition of 64-bit integers might take *two*.  (An add for the lower-order 32 bits, followed by an add-with-carry for the upper-order 32 bits.)  So your GCD algorithm might take twice as long for 64- (as opposed to 32-) bit integers.

For this reason, **we usually drop constant prefactors when analyzing the complexity of an algorithm**.  (This is the mathematical definition of $O$, if you've seen that.)  If an algorithm takes twice as long as you want, then just wait 6 months and Moore's Law will fix your problem.  If it scales like $O(2^n)$, then Moore's law will never help you.

**Change the "time unit" of your computation to be "two CPU operations."**  Call this a "double-CPU operation."  **Then your algorithm consumes a bit on each double-CPU operation**; thus, it takes at most $(\log{|x|}+\log{|y|})$-many double-steps.  Converting back to the usual units, your algorithm takes at most $2(\log{|x|}+\log{|y|})$-many steps.

**Since your algorithm takes at most $2\cdot(\text{logs})$ time, it is indeed $O(\text{logs})$.**

Comment: The algorithm is a modification of GCD and each step is a recursion. If at each recursion the input is halved, then it is clearly log |size of number in bits| to finish. But if the numbers are halved every second recursion each, is it still considered logarithmic?

Comment: I think the OP is asking about [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity) in the abstract sense, where the models of computation are Turing machines (or similar) and the complexity is independent of ideas like word size or high level arithmetic instructions.

Comment: @RobArthan: Yes that is right. Basically if the processing is done on a number that has |N| bits (arbitrarily long stream of bits) it would be O(N) if the processing is dependent on the number of bits

Comment: @RobArthan: Yes, my discussion of word size etc. is to motivate why abstract computational complexity is defined the way it is.  Maybe it wasn't necessary for the question.

Comment: @Jim: "it would be O(N) if the processing is dependent on the number of bits" — only if the processing time is _at most linear_ in the number of bits.  A program taking time quadratic in the number of bits depends on the number of bits, but isn't $O(N)$!

Comment: @JacobManaker: I didn't understand what you mean. If we have e.g. $2048$ bits and we have an algorithm that at each step checks a bit, then the algorithm would finish after $2048$ checks right? So it would be $O(N)$ where $N$ is the number of bits, is that not correct?

Comment: @Jim : Yes.  The point is that not only does it depend on each bit, but it only needs to check that bit _once_ (or, since we discard constant prefactors, a constant number of times).  You can imagine algorithms that depend on each bit, and moreover need to go back and recheck that bit an unbounded number of times.

Comment: Ok, for the original post each bit is checked once from the algorithm (Eclidean GCD variant). Additionally the input is halved at every *2nd step* and not at each step. Would that make it logarithmic?

Comment: @Jim.  **Yes, it is.  I feel like I've said that in the answer, but maybe I wasn't explicit enough.**  We say that $\log{(n)}$ is logarithmic, we say that $2\log{(n)}$ is logarithmic, we say that $\frac{1}{2}\log{(n)}$ is logarithmic…​ **you've shown that your algorithm takes at most $2\log{(n)}$ time, just by changing the "unit" of computation to be two steps rather than one.  And that's still logarithmic.**

Comment: I've edited to incorporate that point about changing units from my previous comment into the answer.  I think maybe I was assuming that, and that's what confused you.

Comment: Thank you for the update. The part that is not clear to me which is the core of my original question is: `Then your algorithm consumes a bit on each double-CPU operation; thus, it takes at most (log||+log||)-many double-steps`. It is not obvious to me that we can still claim $log$. The part that $2\cdot log = O(log)$ is clear

Comment: @Jim: How did you conclude that the complexity is $\log{(|x|)}+\log{(|y|)}$ if both input numbers are a power of two?  Along the way, you need to have an argument of the form: "if my algorithm reads exactly one new bit if the input $n$ in each step, then it takes $\log{(|n|)}$ time."  That selfsame argument should apply to the general case with rescaled units.

Comment: Because we are halving each number at *each* step. This is by definition $log(|x|)$ for number $x$ and $log(|y|)$ for number $y$ right? But I am not sure how to prove that if we  half something at $k > 1$ it is still logarithmic. Is there e.g. some limit that if $k > r$ then it is something other than logarithmic?

Comment: @Jim: "This is by definition $\log{(|x|)}$" — not exactly.  Since you halve a number in each step, you can show by induction that, if $(x\text{ after }k\text{ steps})\leq1$, then $x\leq2^k$.  Then solve for $k$.

Comment: My point is, group the steps into pairs of two.  In the worst case, the modified algorithm which you are asking about halves each number at _each_ group-of-$2$-steps.  It thus takes $\log{(|x|)}$-many 2-steps, either "by definition" or by my argument above.  Now unbundle the steps: you have at most $2\log{(|x|)}$-many 1-steps.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "some limit".

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I believe this is known as [Stein's algorithm, binary GCD, or binary Euclidean GCD.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm)

You can read about the complexity of it [here](https://codility.com/media/train/10-Gcd.pdf), and it has some references to the complexities of other GCD algorithms too which might help.

I'm not too sure, but I think what you're saying is on the right track, and the wikipedia's mentioning of the complexity being on the order of $log(max(u, v))$ might be similar to your logic.

Comment: What I am not sure is that if we half something at bigger intervals than just one step, does that affect it being logarithmic?